# Parsing type names

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

Let's say I've got a string such as `string values = "hello 2 88.9 true"` which holds several values of different types. I have several variables which were declared with the appropriate types (here a string, an int, a float and a bool). What I basically want to do is this :

```
field0 = getValue(0,values);
field1 = getValue(1,values);
... etc
```

So what I want is a `getValue` whose return type matches the type of the corresponding field. Is this possible with simply templates ? I feel like you cannot just specify the return type you want to use without having the template type in the parameters of the template function.
The body of the function itself is probably going to use boost's lexical_cast and a stringstream but if you have a better solution, I'm up for that as well !

I'm new to templates so I would very much appreciate an explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;

string a;
int b;
double c;
bool d;

string values = "hello 2 88.9 true";
stringstream in(values);
in >> a >> b >> c >> std::boolalpha >> d;
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks ! Are there other types such as bool which won't be handled by stringstream ? The string `values` is actually coming from a TCP port, I'm not supposed to know what I'm receiving before run-time. But I don't want to have an unpleasant surprise obviously so I want the code to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Be aware that if your input is "1 2.3 true" where the first string field is absent, the variable a, b, c and d will be 1, 2, 0.3, true respectively. But since the input is ill-formed, there is not a correct way to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::stringstream ss;
ss << values;
ss >> field0 >> field1 >> field2 >> field3;
```

If I really wanted it as a `getValue` function, I *might* do it the crude-but-effective way:

```
template<typename T>
void getValue(unsigned int n, string str, T &val)
{
  string junk;
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  for(unsigned int k=0; k<n; ++k)
    ss >> junk;
  ss >> val;
  return;
}
```